# How do I post one image at a time instead of the whole folder?

Tags: php, forms, image, post, file-upload

Here's my code, right now all the images are being uploaded and displayed upon the click of the post button, I'm trying to get them to display one at a time after hitting the post button, I've tried losing the continue statement after the if statement but that results in broken images.I've tried adding a break after the output, but then of course only the initial image gets displayed, Any suggestions?

```
<?php  
$folder = "images/";

if(isset($_POST['post'])){
    if (is_dir($folder)) 
    {
        if ($open = opendir($folder)) 
        {
            while (($file = readdir($open)) != false)
            {
                if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')continue;
                {
                    echo '<img src = "images/'.$file.'" width = "150" height = 150>';
                }
            }

            closedir($open);
        }
    }


    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) 
    {
        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_tem_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_store = "images/".$file_name;

        if (move_uploaded_file($file_tem_loc, $file_store)) 
        {
            echo "files successfully uploaded";
        }
    }

}

?>

<form action = "?" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">

    <label>Uploading Files</label>
    <p><input type = "file" name = "file"/> </p>
    <p> <input type = "submit" name = "upload" value = "Upload Images"> </p>
    <p> <input type = "submit" name = "post" value = "Post"> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: You are just showing the Images in a particular directory. Since you kept if (isset($_POST['upload'])) inside if(isset($_POST['post'])) the upload functionalities is not going to work

Comment: What is your exact requirements

Comment: yeah I've noticed that my only requirements are to post one picture at a time instead of the whole folder , and that the files don't have to be in a specific directory

Comment: Please try to move the  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) out of the other condition

Comment: I've tried that and got the same results

Comment: or at least it's the same as far as posting goes, but yeah it does upload successfully

Comment: Still don't get your question. What is the purpose of keeping 2 submit buttons in the form? What each buttons does when clicked?

Comment: sorry about that the upload button is not necessary i just want people to be able to post pictures from any directory and have them displayed on the web page

Comment: right now it's posting everything in the folder as soon as I hit post without even selecting a file, sorry for the mess

Comment: It is not uploading everything but showing what you already uploaded into the images folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code,

```
<?php  
$folder = "images/";
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) 
{
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_tem_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_store = "images/".date('YmdHis').'_'.$file_name;

    if (move_uploaded_file($file_tem_loc, $file_store)) 
    {
        echo "<h3>File successfully uploaded<br>Here is the image that you recently uploaded</h3>";
        echo '<img src = "'.$file_store.'" width = "150" height = 150>';
    }
}

echo "<h3>Here are the images that you uploaded so far</h3>";
if (is_dir($folder)) 
{
    if ($open = opendir($folder)) 
    {
        while (($file = readdir($open)) != false)
        {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')continue;
            {
                echo '<img src = "images/'.$file.'" width = "150" height = 150>';
            }
        }
        closedir($open);
    }
} ?>

<form action="?" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Uploading Files</label>
    <p><input type = "file" name = "file"/> </p>
    <p> <input type = "submit" name = "upload" value = "Upload Images"> </p>
    <!--<p> <input type = "submit" name = "post" value = "Post"> </p>-->
</form>
```

Please note that I have renamed the uploaded file name by appending timestamp with the file name to avoid possibilty of uploading multiple images with the same in which case it will either overwrite the existing file or will not allow to upload new file

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm trying to do, do you know how I'd post one image at a time via the post button?

Comment: @abiel, It actually uploads only one file at a time. Do you want to select multiple files to upload then it should upload one file at a time progressively?